# Export Data Extension data to Email, not FTP?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automation, ftp

Does anyone know if it's possible to export Marketing Cloud Data Extensions to Email, not FTP?

In addition, if this could be scheduled to happen automatically?

We have automations in place that populate/update our Data Extensions which is why we want to track these changes.

Comment: How big is the data extension?

Comment: They will vary in size. Some will definitely over 50MB / few hundred thousand records with 50+ fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

No

**Explanation:**

The two methods of exporting data from a data extension are :

1. If the file is less than 20 MB it can be downloaded to your pc.
2. Files larger than this will have to be collected from the FTP location.

**Reference:** [Exporting Data Extensions](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/exporting_a_data_extension/)

NB:

For security reasons, your administrator might have set the export to the FTP regardless of size.

**Caveat:**

As with most things, it is possible to hack this. You would need to create an email and use the [Attach Ampscript](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/attachfile2/#AttachFile) function to send it yourself.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for this!

Based on that AMPscript link, in theory - would the flow go about this : 

Automation studio to first create the Export file from Data Extension, then send email with that AMPscript function with the exported file being attached?

What I'm wondering is how will it know to pick the correct file every day.

Comment: The best way to avoid this out be not to set wild cards on the export definition i.e. File.csv. This way it overwrites the file in the ftp, but you would have it saved in emails and the data extension

Comment: You could also write another Ampscript function that calculates the wildcard for the export job I.e timestamp and append it to the variables in Attach file call